# What is the right architecture for scalably scheduling and managing frequent periodic asynchronous?

Tags: asynchronous-programming

I have built a setup which solves my problem, but I've pretty much just hacked it together by reading AWS docs and trying things out, so I want to see if there is a better way.

For the purpose of this discussion let us define a "task" to be a set of processes which 1) gathers data, 2) processes the data, and 3) stores the processed data.  Assume that all tasks are independent, meaning that each task can be carried out regard to the status of any other task.  At any given moment there is a list of tasks which are to be completed asynchronously at regular time intervals (say, every 2 minutes).

Currently I'm using what I'll call a "one task per instance" model.  This means that every 2 minutes a scheduler puts each task on the list in a queue, and a collection of worker instances read from the queue and perform the tasks from start to finish asynchronously.  This works pretty well, but I run into trouble on rare occasions when a task takes too long and ties up one of the instances.  Also, there is a lot of idle time after a task is completed (usually only 30 seconds or so) and before the next round of scheduled tasks.

So I'm thinking about switching to what I'll call an "assembly line" model.  This would mean having one collection of instances which are experts on the first part of a task (gathering data), another collection which are experts on the second part (processing data), and so on.  By specializing the instances, my hope is that I would be able to more efficiently achieve the same rate of processing for each task (once every 2 minutes) and reduce the risk of a log jam if one part of one task takes too long.  The main downside that I can see is it would require more coordination between instances: the data processing instances would have to wait fore the data gathering instances to finish and so on.  And I've never really done anything like this before, so I'm worried about rebuilding my entire setup only to be crippled by an unforeseen flaw.

So what do people think?  Are there reasons to prefer the assembly line to one task per instance?  Are there ways to improve or streamline either model as I've described it?  Is there an even better model that I haven't thought of?

Comment: I understand how one task taking too long is an issue but I don't understand why having 30 seconds of idle time is an issue.  If you need them to execute in every two minutes then being finished before 2 minutes is up seems like a good thing.  is the 2 minute thing a requirement or some sort of implementation detail that you added?

Comment: @JimmyJames The 2 minute thing is basically an implementation detail; the scheduler uses cron notation, and I don't think it accepts seconds.  I used 2 minutes instead of 1 minute since the tasks occasionally take 1 minute but almost never 2 minutes.  There might also be some cost issues, i.e. if I had to choose I'd rather save processors than save time.

Comment: So would you want to start the next cycle when the first is done?

Comment: @JimmyJames Basically, yes.  In practice the frontend interface which displays the data is rate limited at about 1 update per minute, but there's no harm in updating the data faster.

Answer (score 1):

Two minutes seems like a long time.

Is that time interval there to insure that all tasks get completed by the next round?  If that's the case, then why not just spin up a thread or Task for each "set of processes," and simply let that thread run to completion?  Your scheduler could then run, say, once per second, and make much better use of the computing resources instead of sitting idle most of the time.

You might also be interested in the Disruptor, a form of ring buffer that specializes in the kind of processing you described, although an ordinary Priority Queue might suffice.  The Disruptor looks like this:

[image]

**Further Reading**
[LMax Architecture by Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/articles/lmax.html)
[The LMAX Disruptor](http://lmax-exchange.github.io/disruptor/)

Comment: I agree that I should keep track of each task's state and run the scheduler more frequently; the 2 minute thing is more an implementation quirk than anything else.  In any case, the Disruptor paradigm does indeed look well-adapted to my use-case; I'll take a closer look.

Answer (score 0):

There's multiple ways of accomplishing this type of architecture. They do share some similarities (in that there's a "task manager", possibly running in multiple instances for reliability; and workers, grabbing tasks from the manager), so let me walk through the pieces.

The core is the "task manager", this has one or more queues of "items available to be worked on". Any item acquired is done so under a "lease" (we'll get back to this later) and once a worker has completed an item, it's marked as "done". Typically, work items are handed out either "from the front of the queue" (using some sort of priority, maybe as simple as FIFO) or "randomly" (pick any item).

A worker starts by leasing a work item from the manager, chugging away at it, then (once done) marking it as complete.

By separating leasing a work item (this basically means "it's being worked on") from completing a work item, you can guard against "the worker died" or "the worker is inexplicably slow". Although using this property means you need to ensure that work items are idempotent (that is, it doesn't matter if you complete a given item more than once) or ensure that all work done is transactional, so a failed completion doesn't leave things half-done.

You can then use either close to what you have (single queue) or let a worker schedule "stage n+1" with the manager, to get more of an assembly line.

You probably also want some sort of supervisor function, so that failed workers can be restarted. This could either be part of the task manager or something external to workers/manager.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I would qualify this as architecture (I concede that the term is a bit nebulous.)  You are essentially asking how to implement repeating set of tasks, a.k.a. a loop.  To me this is more of an implementation issue.

I think the simplest approach would be to submit each independent task on a worker pool and use a countdown latch approach to determine when all the threads have returned a result.  Rinse and repeat.  I would recommend putting in a throttle that guarantees no more than N executions in a given time frame, so you prevent this from spinning if something goes wrong.